# How I can use Counter object with named tuples

Tags: python

I have following `namedtuple`:

```
ErrorProbeData = namedtuple('ErrorProbeData', 
    ['project_name', 'probe_id', 'number_invalid_votes', 'masker_id'])
```

How I can count by `Counter` the tuples by `'project_name'` field?
the tuples are located in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to feed *just* the project name values to the counter:

```
Counter(epd.project_name for epd in list_of_epds)
```

Named tuples are not special here; this would apply to any problem where you want to count by a specific attribute (objects), key (mappings) or index (sequences). You need to loop and extract, and a generator expression helps avoid creating an intermediary list for this.